# Trying to DESELECT range of cells in Excel after using ClearContents in .bas file using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am working in Excel 2016 and am trying to do 3 things in my .bas file:
1). Clear contents in excel file in multiple worksheets.

2). DESELECT the SELECTED cells where the CLEAR CONTENTS code executed.

3). SELECT the `A1` cell.

I cannot find a way to do step 2 and could use some help/direction.  Thanks.

Here is the vba code:

```
Sub ClearContentsAllWorksheetsInWorkbook()

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Cells.ClearContents
    Range("A1").Select
    Range("A1").Activate
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `Application.GoTo ws.Range("A1"), True`. I'd add some additional checks, such as `If Not ws.ProtectContents And ws.EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions And ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then`

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "REMOVE the SELECTED cells..."? The cells are now empty of all content and formatting since you cleared them.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad, my apologies, I should have said DESELECT the selected cells.  Sorry about.  Thanks for pointing that out.  I'll correct the post.

Comment: @BigBen, unfortunately, that did not work.  I added the Application... line right below the ws.Cells.ClearContents line and I got a run-time error '1004': Method Range of object_Worksheet failed.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: Did you get rid of the `Range("A1").Select` and `Range("A1").Activate`?

Comment: @FaneDuru, I tried what you said but got another error:  Select method of Range class failed.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to `Activate` and `Select`, then you can use [`Application.GoTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.goto) with the `Scroll` argument as `True`.

```
Application.GoTo ws.Range("A1"), True
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell VBA precisely that you want to select/activate each sheet. Unfortunately you cannot do it in one line ws.range("a1").activate won't work - split it into two lines of code.

```
Sub ClearContentsAllWorksheetsInWorkbook()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Cells.ClearContents
        With ws
            .Activate
            .Range("A1").Activate
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub
```